# How to permanently install Realtek HD audio drivers

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

When I updated to Windows 10 the audio quality for none Windows applications dropped a lot.  I fixed this by downloading a different version of realtek audio drivers and then running the .exe thus installing it.

This fixes the problem perfectly however, the next time I start up the computer the audio reverts to its original quality until I reinstall the drivers again.

Does anyone know how I can install the driver permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this when you have audio quality problem (i.e. after restart)

1. Recommended: create a system restore point.
2. Go to `run` and type `devmgmt.msc` and press enter to open device manager.
3. In device manager, under `Sound, video, and game controllers` find `High definition Audio` driver and right-click it. Choose properties, under the `Driver` tab choose `Driver Details`. Look for one of driver file names, located under `C:\windows\system32\drivers`.
4. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository` and in the search box, type in one of the driver file names you found in device manager. (in my case, it's `RTKVHD64.sys`, `AERTAR64.dll`, or `RTAIODAT.DAT`). Now, right click on the found file, and choose `Open file location`. You are in the driver folder now, at the address bar in explorer, click on `FileRepository` to go back to main folder. Now, right click the highlighted folder and choose `Properties`, go to `Security` tab and choose `Advanced`. In front of Owner click `Change` and type in your username and click ok. Check the box `Replace owner on subcontainer and objects` and click ok. Now, in the `Security` tab again, choose `Edit` and `Add` your user account and grant it `Full control`. Apply and exit the Properties. Now, you can 
   delete or cut the highlighted folder to somewhere else.
5. Go back to device manager and on the open driver properties, choose `Uninstall` and check the box `Delete the driver software for this device`. Restart if required, then manually install your driver.

From now on, it can't revert to previous driver, because it no longer exists.

**Disclaimer: Do it at your own risk! I'm not responsible for any critical driver deleted by mistake!**